# Getting error while reading data from Azure Devops Odata Query

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, tfs, odata

I m running below code to fetch to get Odata query but getting auth error

```
import requests
import json
endpoint_url = "https://analytics.dev.azure.com/pbi0280/TestOdata/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId,WorkItemType,Title,State"
pat = "vch3ufmtbnimclfumrms5vgulcktrtakhp2hig3p7v3cs3ormi7q"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + pat}
response = requests.get(endpoint_url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(open(response.text,encoding='utf-8-sig'))
print(data)
```

Error :
No such file or directory: '\ufeff{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}'

When I m running same url in web, its working fine and json output.

[image]

Comment: You should never ask questions with sensitive information into them. You've published your PAT and Azure DevOps organization and project. You should immediately revoke the PAT to safe guard your environments.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps does not support `Authorization: Bearer` with personal access tokens (PAT). They must be supplied using basic authentication. The user name can be left blank but the PAT must be supplied as the password.

Switch over to basic authentication and your code should work fine.